# iOS - Storyboard - Delegate for pop over

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, storyboard

I'm using storyboard in my ipad application and successfully able to do transitions, use segues etc. 
Currently I am showing pop over view controller on click of a button. I want to detect when the pop over dismisses.
How can I do it?

Comment: Sadly, none of the answers below work in iOS 8 because the segue sent to prepareForSegue is not a UIStoryboardPopoverSegue. Odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a segue in view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popSegue;
```

In XIB, create an identifier called "popover" for the view.

In Interface, write the following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popover"] )
    {
        //[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        NSLog(@"%@",[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers]);
        self.popSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
.
.
.
}
```

Write the following code to dismiss the pop over by coding:

```
[self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I did:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popover"])
    {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *pop = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
        pop.popoverController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: UIStoryboardPopoverSegue is deprecated : first deprecated in ios9.0-  access destinationviewcontroller.popoverpresentationconroller from your segue perform handler or override of perform... that to do for this!!!!

Answer (score 7):

### UIPopoverController

Now with my revelation that you're talking about a `UIPopoverController`, here are the steps:

1. Setup the `UIPopoverController` with an appropriate delegate (I'm assuming the "sender" view controller)
2. Have your "sender" conform to the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`
3. Implement the `– popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` message and have any detection logic here
4. Implement `- prepareForSegue:sender:` and use the segue's `destinationController` to both get a reference and set the delegate, something like below:

   ((MyViewController*)segue.destinationController).delegate = self;

---

### Modal View Controller

1. Add a delegate to the view controller that is being presented
2. Name your segue if you haven't already
3. Have your base view controller implement `- prepareForSegue:sender:` (refer to the [`UIViewController documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html))
4. Assign the sending view controller as the modal view controller's delegate in `prepareForSegue:sender:`
5. Call a desired method on the delegate immediately before or after you call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

That is how I would approach this. I would also recommend having a formal protocol to conform your sending view controller with.

Comment: This is the regular way of writing them. I am following the same procedure to handle tableview inside my popover. Its working fine. But how to add delegate for pop over itself?

Comment: Your question is already in my answer. Can you be more specific about what you're confused about?

Comment: You explained how to set the delegate for the view being shown in pop over and not for the pop over itself. I want to set delegate for pop over view in my root view controller.

Comment: Didn't you say that you wanted the *sender* to be notified when the *modal* view controller dismisses itself? Just do the work in the delegated method you define (the one invoked in step 5).

Comment: Pop over itself has delegates. I want to implement that method and not custom one.

Comment: Whoops. I misread; you're talking about the `UIPopoverController` class. I'll put together a better reference. I figured you were just talking about a simple modal view controller.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include details on the `UIPopoverController`. I'll leave the modal view controller details for anyone else that happens on this question in the future. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Coming back to the starting point, I'm using story board and segues to show the popover. How can I set the delegate of popover in root view controller. so that on close of popover it calls the delegate appropriately.

Comment: You should be able to set that all up in the `- prepareForSegue:sender:` caller on your sender. Get a reference to the segue and utilize its `destinationController` property.

Comment: I know that we've to set it in prePareForSegue. Do you have exact answer of how to set the delegate. I tried all the options of getting destinationController and view controllers in it etc.... but i'm not getting any pointer to pop over.

Comment: I'm guess I'm not understanding what your issue is. Any way you can help me out clarity wise?

Comment: On click of a button, I am showing pop over using segues in story board. The ways you are suggesting works for the controller in side the pop over and not for pop over itself. I don't want delegate for view controller inside popover. But I want the delegate for pop over itself. When popover closes it calls the delegate "didDismiss". I want to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Since `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`is deprecated in iOS 9, you can use a `UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegue`.

Then in `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`you can set the delegate like this:

### Swift:

```
if let identifier = segue.identifier where identifier == "showPopover" {
    let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController

    destVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Objective-C code for the question is below.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"home_login"]) 
{
   UIViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
   dest.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL) popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
{
    return NO;
}
```